# MediaCodec/MediaExtractor - libexynosv4l2 error when trying to queueInputBuffer from second MediaExtractor to second decoder

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, mediaextractor

In my quest to try concatenating videos with MediaCodec, I'm trying to use two `MediaExtractor`s, each paired with `MediaCodec`s as decoders. I tried localizing the Extractor and Decoder loops so they look like this:

```
private void videoExtractorLoop(MediaExtractor localVideoExtractor, MediaCodec destinationDecoder, ByteBuffer[] destinationDecoderInputBuffers)
{
    boolean localExtractorIsOrig = (localVideoExtractor == videoExtractor);
    boolean localDoneIndicator = localExtractorIsOrig ? videoExtractorDone : videoExtractorAppendDone;

    while (mCopyVideo && !localDoneIndicator && (encoderOutputVideoFormat == null || muxing)) {
        int decoderInputBufferIndex = destinationDecoder.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);
        if (decoderInputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
            if (VERBOSE)
                Log.d(TAG, "no video decoder input buffer");
            break;
        }
        if (VERBOSE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "video decoder: returned input buffer: "
                    + decoderInputBufferIndex);
        }
        ByteBuffer decoderInputBuffer = destinationDecoderInputBuffers[decoderInputBufferIndex];
        int size = localVideoExtractor.readSampleData(decoderInputBuffer, 0);
        long presentationTime = localVideoExtractor.getSampleTime();
        if (VERBOSE) {
            Log.d(TAG, (localVideoExtractor == videoExtractor) + " video extractor: returned buffer of size "
                    + size);
            Log.d(TAG, (localVideoExtractor == videoExtractor) + " video extractor: returned buffer for time "
                    + presentationTime);
        }
        if (size >= 0) {
            if(localExtractorIsOrig)firstDecoderFinalFrameTimestamp = presentationTime;
            destinationDecoder.queueInputBuffer(decoderInputBufferIndex, 0, size, presentationTime, localVideoExtractor.getSampleFlags());
        }
        if(localExtractorIsOrig)
        {videoExtractorDone = !localVideoExtractor.advance();}
        else
        {
            videoExtractorAppendDone = !localVideoExtractor.advance();
        }
        if (videoExtractorDone) {
            if (VERBOSE)
                Log.d(TAG, "video extractor: EOS");
            if(localExtractorIsOrig && destinationDecoder == videoDecoder){destinationDecoder.queueInputBuffer(decoderInputBufferIndex, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);}
            else if(!localExtractorIsOrig && destinationDecoder == videoDecoderAppend){destinationDecoder.queueInputBuffer(decoderInputBufferIndex, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);}
            //videoDecoder.queueInputBuffer(decoderInputBufferIndex, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);
        }
        videoExtractedFrameCount++;
        break;
    }
    //Video Extractor code end
}

private void localizedVideoDecoderLoop(MediaCodec localVideoDecoder, OutputSurface localVidDecoderOutputSurface, InputSurface dstEncoderInputSurface, ByteBuffer[] locDecoderOutputBuffers)
{
    boolean localDecoderIsOrig = (localVideoDecoder == videoDecoder);
    boolean localDoneIndicator = localDecoderIsOrig ? videoDecoderDone : videoDecoderAppendDone;
    MediaFormat localDecoderOutFormat = localDecoderIsOrig ? decoderOutputVideoFormat : decoderOutputAppendVideoFormat;
    Log.i("check_local_decoder", localDecoderIsOrig+"");
    MediaCodec.BufferInfo localDecoderOutBufInfo = localDecoderIsOrig ? videoDecoderOutputBufferInfo : videoDecoderAppendOutputBufferInfo;
    //Video Decoder code begin
    while (mCopyVideo && !localDoneIndicator && (encoderOutputVideoFormat == null || muxing)) {
        int decoderOutputBufferIndex = localVideoDecoder.dequeueOutputBuffer(localDecoderOutBufInfo, TIMEOUT_USEC);
        if (decoderOutputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
            if (VERBOSE)
                Log.d(TAG, "no video decoder output buffer");
            break;
        }
        if (decoderOutputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_BUFFERS_CHANGED) {
            if (VERBOSE)
                Log.d(TAG, "video decoder: output buffers changed");
            if(localDecoderIsOrig){videoDecoderOutputBuffers = localVideoDecoder.getOutputBuffers();}
            else {videoDecoderAppendOutputBuffers = localVideoDecoder.getOutputBuffers();}
            break;
        }
        if (decoderOutputBufferIndex == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
            if(localDecoderIsOrig){decoderOutputVideoFormat = localVideoDecoder.getOutputFormat();}
            else{decoderOutputAppendVideoFormat = localVideoDecoder.getOutputFormat();}
            Log.i("decoder_vid_out_format", localDecoderOutFormat+"");
            if (VERBOSE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "video decoder: output format changed: "
                        + localDecoderOutFormat);
            }
            break;
        }
        if (VERBOSE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "video decoder: returned output buffer: "
                    + decoderOutputBufferIndex);
            Log.d(TAG, "video decoder: returned buffer of size "
                    + localDecoderOutBufInfo.size);
            Log.d(TAG, "video decoder: returned buffer for time "
                    + localDecoderOutBufInfo.presentationTimeUs);
        }
        ByteBuffer decoderOutputBuffer = locDecoderOutputBuffers[decoderOutputBufferIndex];
        if ((localDecoderOutBufInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG) != 0) {
            if (VERBOSE)
                Log.d(TAG, "video decoder: codec config buffer");
            localVideoDecoder.releaseOutputBuffer(decoderOutputBufferIndex,
                    false);
            break;
        }
        if (VERBOSE) {
            Log.d(TAG, "video decoder: returned buffer for time "
                    + localDecoderOutBufInfo.presentationTimeUs);
        }
        boolean render = localDecoderOutBufInfo.size != 0;
        localVideoDecoder.releaseOutputBuffer(decoderOutputBufferIndex,
                render);
        if (render) {
            renderingFrameSection(localVidDecoderOutputSurface, dstEncoderInputSurface, localDecoderOutBufInfo.presentationTimeUs);
        }
        videoDecodedFrameCount++;
        if ((localDecoderOutBufInfo.flags & MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
            if (VERBOSE)
                Log.d(TAG, "video decoder: EOS");
            if(localDecoderIsOrig){videoDecoderDone = true;}
            else{videoDecoderAppendDone = true;}
            if(!localDecoderIsOrig){videoEncoder.signalEndOfInputStream();}
        }
        break;
    }
    //Video Decoder code end
}
```

I use these functions in the usual ExtractDecodeEditEncodeTest in the place of the Extractor code and Decoder code respectively. I just pass in the `MediaExtractor` and the decoder `MediaCodec` I want to use, and I expected the function to do the usual extraction/decoding loop with said extractor and decoder.

When I use these functions for the first extractor-decoder pair, they worked fine. However, when I use them for the second extractor-decoder pair immediately after the first one's work was finished, I get the following exception from the line `destinationDecoder.queueInputBuffer(decoderInputBufferIndex, 0, 0, 0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM);`:

`W/System.err: android.media.MediaCodec$CodecException: Error 0xfffffff3`

EDIT:

I looked closer in the stacktrace and found these:

```
10-07 10:37:39.697 3061-25956/? I/EXYNOS_BASE_COMP: [0xf1459700][Exynos_OMX_ComponentStateSet] current:(OMX_StateLoaded) dest:(OMX_StateIdle)
10-07 10:37:39.697 23904-25949/com.picmix.mobile I/ACodec: [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] Now Loaded->Idle
10-07 10:37:39.707 23904-25949/com.picmix.mobile D/SurfaceUtils: set up nativeWindow 0x7f76e82010 for 400x224, color 0x105, rotation 0, usage 0x2900
10-07 10:37:39.707 23904-25949/com.picmix.mobile I/ACodec: [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] configureOutputBuffersFromNativeWindow setBufferCount : 7, minUndequeuedBuffers : 5
10-07 10:37:39.707 3061-25956/? D/libexynosv4l2: try node: /dev/video6
10-07 10:37:39.707 3061-25956/? I/libexynosv4l2: node found for device s5p-mfc-dec: /dev/video6
10-07 10:37:39.707 23904-25929/com.picmix.mobile I/check_local_decoder: false
10-07 10:37:39.707 3061-25956/? I/libexynosv4l2: open video device /dev/video6
10-07 10:37:39.717 3061-25956/? I/EXYNOS_BASE_COMP: [0xf1459700][Exynos_OMX_ComponentStateSet]:567 OMX_EventCmdComplete
10-07 10:37:39.717 3061-25956/? I/EXYNOS_BASE_COMP: [0xf1459700][Exynos_OMX_ComponentStateSet] current:(OMX_StateIdle) dest:(OMX_StateExecuting)
10-07 10:37:39.717 3061-25956/? I/EXYNOS_BASE_COMP: [0xf1459700][Exynos_OMX_ComponentStateSet]:567 OMX_EventCmdComplete
10-07 10:37:39.717 23904-25949/com.picmix.mobile I/ACodec: [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] Now Idle->Executing
10-07 10:37:39.717 23904-25949/com.picmix.mobile I/ACodec: [OMX.Exynos.avc.dec] Now Executing
10-07 10:37:39.717 3061-25979/? E/libexynosv4l2: failed to ioctl: VIDIOC_S_CTRL (22)
10-07 10:37:39.717 3061-25979/? E/EXYNOS_H264_DEC: Failed to set buffer process type(not supported)
10-07 10:37:39.717 3061-25979/? E/libexynosv4l2: failed to ioctl: VIDIOC_G_CTRL (22 - Invalid argument)
```

What do I need to change in the Decoder settings?

Comment: have you found any solution?